# How disable wrong options in selects depend on selected option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to create a simple math practising js script.

For example:
The sum is given (=10) and there are four select with numbers from 0 to 10.
And if I choose a number I should disable the wrong options. I mean, the sum of selected options can not bigger then 10.

I tried this way: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/yMP8f/)

```
$(document).on("change", "select.number", function(){
    var sum = 10;
    var number = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    var sum_number = 0;

    $("select.number option:selected").each(function(){
        sum_number = parseInt($(this).val(),10) + parseInt(sum_number,10);
    });    

    $("select.number option").attr("disabled", false);

    if(sum_number>0){
        var act_person = act_max_person = 0;
        $("select.number").each(function(){
            $(this).children("option:not(:first)").each(function(){   // first is 0
                if(parseInt($(this).val(),10) + parseInt(sum_number,10) > sum) $(this).attr("disabled", true);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

But it's vary far from the perfect...

Comment: You can get the value of a select element using `$("select").val()`, you don't have to find the child `option:selected` manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).on("change", "select.number", function () {
    var sum = 10;
    var number = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

    var sum_number = 0;
    $("select.number option:selected").each(function () {
        sum_number += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    });

    $('select.number option').prop('disabled', false);
    if (sum_number > 0) {
        var diff = sum - sum_number;
        $('select.number').each(function () {
            var idx = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) + diff + 1;
            $(this).find('option').slice(idx).prop('disabled', true)
        })
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/erdq8/)

Comment: Absolutely perfect!!!! I've just finished my breakfast and wow..Thank you for your fast reply.